# Clipping cross-sections by flood area using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cross-section, clip

I have a problem with clipping cross-sections by flood area. I have source cross-sections that goes beyond the flood area:

[image]

When I clipped it by "Clip" tool I have this:
[image]

But I needs this:
[image]

It must be automatic because I have thousands of cross-sections.

Can anyone help me?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Try changing symbology on your polygon so it is filled. Then you see why. It'll only clip the polygons where one exists. In the areas where you are not getting a line, it's because there aint no polygon to clip.

Comment: I'd create a hull from your flood area polygons and clip the cross-sections to that. Most GIS offer a convex hull tool, but I think you may need a concave hull, which is a bit trickier to define and the tools to do so are somewhat less common. I'm not sure whether ArcGIS has the appropriate tool or not. I'm fairly certain that QGIS will let you calculate the concave hull though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think there will be an obvious automatic solution with the line features because you are trying to keep geometry that is both inside and outside your green flood area - and any tool will be unable to distinguish which parts to keep.

One alternative to try is to convert your cross-sections and flood areas to polygons and clip the output to the parts you want (I would need to try it but I think you should be able to use the attribute table to identify the parts you are after). The [feature to polygon tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000) in Arc is only available on the advanced licence but if you download the free [ET GeoWizards toolbar](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_main.htm) there is a an equivalent tool that may do the job.

[image: ET GeoWizards tool]